# how to use aggregate function in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm working on the following document

```
{
"_id" : 12,
"firstName" : "wer",
"People" : [ 
    {
        "uuid" : "123",
        "name" : "sugun",
        "person" : [ 
            {
                "uuid" : "add32",
                "name" : "ssss"
            }, 
            {
                "uuid" : "fdg456",
                "name" : "gfg"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "uuid" : "222",
        "name" : "kiran"
    }
]
}
```

I want to get my output as following

```
{
"_id" : 456,
"People" : [ 
    {
        "uuid" : "123",
        "name" : "sugun",
        "person" : [ 
            {
                "uuid" : "add32",
                "name" : "ssss"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

when iam using following  command in mongo shell it give my required output

```
 db.people.aggregate([
    {$match: {_id: 12}}, 
    {$unwind: "$People"}, 
    {$unwind: "$People.person"}, 
    {$match: {"People.uuid": "123", "People.person.uuid" : "add32"}}
 ])
```

but  when iam  using same in my meteor app  aggregate is not working......
so can i do the same using find or findOne  methods.............
or if there is any possibility to use aggregate  function  in my meteor app....

Comment: At this point in time I'd recommend http://github.com/JcBernack/meteor-reactive-aggregate, it's working really well for me and has had a commit within the past week

Answer (score 9):

By using `rawCollection` you can pass in the same pipeline that you've been using in your mongo shell.

There is no need to install a third-party package to do this.

```
const stats = await MyCollection.rawCollection()
    .aggregate([
      {$match: {_id: 12}}, 
      {$unwind: "$People"}, 
      {$unwind: "$People.person"}, 
      {$match: {"People.uuid": "123", "People.person.uuid" : "add32"}}
    ])
    .toArray();
```

Comment: Thank you! The .toArray() was the missing bit for me.

Answer (score 5):

I used the meteorhacks:aggregate package. It works only on the server side.

`meteor add meteorhacks:aggregate`

```
MyCollection.aggregate({ 
  $match: { 
    propertyToQuery: 'valueForProperty' 
  }, { 
    $group: {
      _id: '$propertyToGroupBy',
      result: { $operation: '$propertyToPerformOperationOn' }
    }
});
```

https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate

Comment: package seems unmaintained. There are a few forks, but I couldn't get any of them to return values.

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I tried manually and worked for me:

```
var rawUsers = Meteor.users.rawCollection();
var aggregateQuery = Meteor.wrapAsync(rawUsers.aggregate, rawUsers);
var pipeline = [
    {$match: {}},
    {$project: {username: 1, profile: 1}}
];
var result = aggregateQuery(pipeline);

return result;
```

Read more about [Meteor.wrapAsync here](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-wrapAsync)

Comment: make sure to add `cursor` if using 3.6 as `var result = aggregateQuery(pipeline, {cursor: {}});`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a package to expose the `aggregate` feature:

`meteor add monbro:mongodb-mapreduce-aggregation`

Then you can use the code like normal:

```
var MyCollection = new Mongo.Collection('metrics');
var pipeline = [
  {$group: {_id: null, resTime: {$sum: "$resTime"}}}
];

var result = MyCollection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Just a couple of things to note, this works best on the server side. For docs to use it on the client side a fork of the package is needed, check the package's docs: https://atmospherejs.com/monbro/mongodb-mapreduce-aggregation

Comment: hi akshat when i add package  monbro:mongodb-mapreduce-aggregation my app is crashed.....

Comment: Error: A method named '/__dummy__/insert' is already defined at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1444 at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:113)at _.extend.methods (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1442)at Mongo.Collection._define MutationMethods (packages/mongo/collection.js:884)at new Mongo.Collection (packages/mongo/collection.js:208)at Package (packages/monbro:mongodb-mapreduce-aggregatio/server.coffee:7:24)
at packages/monbro:mongodb-mapreduce-aggregation/server.coffee:1

Comment: @GopalRao I'm getting the same error when trying to use the MapReduce function of this package.

Comment: hasn't been updated for 4 years. unlikely to still work.