# Meteor: How to get total amount in budget planner app

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm developing an app for Uni where the user adds in budget items and they get stored in a mongo collection. User makes their own items which are either an income or expense (expense has subcategories) and they are displayed on the screen.

This is all working fine but I need a way to be able to add up all income items and expense items separately and display a total. I know how to do this with just a basic variable I'm adding or subtracting whenever a form is submitted, however, it needs to stay persistent and be saved in the database.

Wondering if there is a way to loop through all the mongo records/objects (not sure what they're called) and add up all the amounts then have them displayed and updated whenever a budget item is added or removed. Sorry if this doesn't make much sense.

I can post the html/js files here (hosted on dropbox?) if needed. Not sure what the easiest way to show the files were but here they are in a [zip archive](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/101934660/budgetPlanner/budgetPlanner.zip) on my dropbox:

Comment: easiest way is to create a meteorpad.com example

Comment: Tried doing it but it just keeps loading and nothing happens after inserting all my code. Sorry I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: It seems to have had issues lately. Still if your code is there post a link, even if the online demo isn't working.

Comment: Hopefully this works - http://meteorpad.com/pad/2q7xBwgYpcpGxMoxJ/Leaderboard

Comment: It seems you have outsourced data crucial for the understanding of your question. Please post all relevant code, images and resources **in the question itself**, if the link dies or changes your question will lose most if not all of its meaning!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use aggregate function in meteor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28425316/how-to-use-aggregate-function-in-meteor)