# Aggregate is not a function - mongodb/meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have this collection (`Spieltag`) with two documents in MongoDB:

```
0: Object Note:2.5 SaisonID:201516 SpielerID:105 SpieltagID:1 Tore:1 _id:"vkD5sMCdZdntoCFGP"

1: Object Note:3 SaisonsID:201516 SpielerID:105 SpieltagID:1 Tore:0 _id:"PrqokMS47K4vx4KR4"
```

I want to summarize `Note` (2.5+1) with a "where clause" on SpielerID.

This is what I have tried to use:

```
Spieltag.aggregate({ $match: {
        { SpielerID: { $gte: 105 } }
} },
{ $group: { _id : null, sum : { $sum: "$Note" } } });
```

But it doesn't work, throwing `Aggregate is not a function`. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use aggregate function in meteor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28425316/how-to-use-aggregate-function-in-meteor)

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to add the aggregate package for Meteor :

```
meteor add meteorhacks:aggregate
```

Second, you must pass an array parameter in aggregate like :

```
Spieltag.aggregate([{
  $match: {
    SpielerID: { $gte: 105 },
  },
}, {
  $group: {
    _id: null,
    sum: { $sum: '$Note' },
  },
}]);
```

Comment: I made an update...

meteorhacks:aggregate         added, version 1.3.0
meteorhacks:collection-utils  added, version 1.2.0
mongo-livedata                added, version 1.0.9

And I insert the above aggregation function to the java script console in chrome. But i get the same error.

Must I insert a statement into my app that this will work?

Comment: I'm sorry, as mentionned in https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate, aggregate only works on the server side. 
To use it on the client you can publish the result of the aggregate function from the server and subscribe to it in the client.

Comment: What I have to do when you say that I must build the aggregate function on the server side?

In my js File I have the following structure...
if (Meteor.isClient) {
...
}

if(Meteor.isServer) {
...
}

At the moment in the Server is only  Meteor.startup(function () {

  }); and the anything else is in the isClient "area"