# JS: Sort object array by creating a kind of map

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary, meteor

I do get my data from mongoDB with

```
Content.find({}).fetch()
```

So there is an array with 1000 documents. Every document has a `category` field.

```
const data = [
    {
        title: 'Article 1',
        category: 'cars'
    },
    {
        title: 'Article 2',
        category: 'vegetables'
    }
]
```

Now I would like to display a list with the documents organized in categories (Getting an own list for each category).
I think the best way I should go is to create a map. But I do not know how to do that.

This is what I am doing:

First I've hardcoded the categories (knowing this is the worst thing I can do)
Then...

```
categories.map(category => {
    return (<List data={data.filter(d => d.category === category)} />)
}
```

With this I will go through 30 categories and do a `filter` on my data 30 times. I think it would be smarter to create a kind of sorted dataset once at the beginning.

Comment: Is grouping data by category on mongodb possible according to your requirements?

Comment: Should be possible, but I'm not quite sure how to do that. I'm using meteorJS, which uses a minimongo instance.

Comment: In mongodb I would write something like `db.Content.aggregate([{$group : {_id : "$category", titles : {$push: "$title"}}}])` which would return a list of titles group by category.

Comment: As far as I know `aggregate` can't be used in minimongo :-(

Comment: Of course you can run `.aggregate()`, but not in minimongo and only as a server side operation. But it is realistically what you "should" be doing and therefore creating a meteor method to wrap the call and return the results. Basic examples are on [how to use aggregate function in meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28425316/how-to-use-aggregate-function-in-meteor). And better examples exist in other answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd prefer using [lodash](https://lodash.com/), then you can sort your data set using [sortBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#sortBy)

```
_.sortBy(data, ['category', 'title']);
data.map(doc => ( console.log(doc); ));
```

This will sort your data ascending first by category and then by title.
OR if you want to break your items into arrays based on category use [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy):

```
_.groupBy(data, 'category');
_.each(data, itemsByCategory => {
  return <List data={itemsByCategory} />;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since aggregating data on mongodb is not an option, I would create a map on the client side by looping once over the data, like:

```
var titlesByCategory = {};
for (let value of data) {
 if (titlesByCategory[data.category]) {
   titlesByCategory[value.category].push(value.title);
 }
  else {
      titlesByCategory[value.category] = [value.title];
  }
}
```

You can then access the array of titles of a given a category just using the category as a key; for instance  `titlesByCategory[vegetables]` will return the array of vegetables over which you can do loop/map or whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

using underscoreJS

```
_.groupBy(data, 'length');
```