# GridFS Collection: howto get total size of all uploaded Files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, gridfs

We have a meteor / node app (wekan fork) and an underlying mongodb.
To store Files we use `cfs:gridfS`.

I know that in the metadata in the files collection when uploading a document is storing the size of that document as length property (correct me if i am wrong).

So i was wondering is there also a way to get the complete size of all files without parsing (adding) them manually?

My Collections:

```
cfs._tempstore.chunks
cfs.attachments.filerecord
cfs_gridfs._tempstore.chunks
cfs_gridfs._tempstore.files
cfs_gridfs.attachments.chunks
cfs_gridfs.attachments.files
```

A 4kb size on disc document in the `cfs_gridfs.attachments.files` collection has two properties:

```
length: 84 // is correct the size of the file but not what it's used on disc
chunksize: 2097152 // don't understand this number, way to much for a 4kb document
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All Files in GridFS are stored in `fs.files` and `fs.chunks`, where a [chunk has a default size of 255KB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/)

Thus you may get the whole size in KB by calculating

```
fs.chunks.find().count() * 255
```

Note that this assumes, that you use the default `db.fs` as your GridFS bucket and the default chunksize.

In Meteor you can get the Grid Collections as every other collection:

```
const FsChunks = new Mongo.Collection('fs.chunks')
```

Edit: this method is somewhat unprecise, because

> The last chunk is only as large as necessary. Similarly, files that are no larger than the chunk size only have a final chunk, using only as much space as needed plus some additional metadata.

So you will get a result that is much larger than the real size, with increasing number of files. It won't be much of problem if you have a few, but large files.

However, other methods still require `aggregate`, which has already been [described well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28425316/how-to-use-aggregate-function-in-meteor), or a manual traversal of `fs.files` and summing up it's `length` property.

Comment: i tried summing up all my uploads by the file.original.size property. But the problem is, i get the real size, not the size, which is used on disc. Any suggestions?

Comment: See also my updated question, with my collections, i tried to make a collection out of `cfs_gridfs.atachments.chunks` but somehow it didnt work out like i hope it would (got a 4kb document but the chunks count returned 1 -> 255)

Answer (score 4):

It's better to get the storage size for the collection using

```
db.fs.chunks.stats()
```

get the storage size from the output.