# Why does MongoDB aggregation match return all documents instead of expected matched documents?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to use MongoDB aggregation in a Meteor application.  I am using Meteor 1.11, which uses MongoDB 4.2.8.  I built and tested my aggregation pipeline with Robo 3T and also tested it with the Mongo shell. It works fine in those contexts, but I can't get it working in a Meteor method.

I narrowed the problem down to the match stage, which is first in the pipeline. When running in a Meteor method, this stage appears to match all documents in the collection. When run in Robo 3T, it returns 4 documents.  Here's how I run it in a Meteor method:

```js
MyCollection
  .rawCollection()
  .aggregate([{$match: {vocabularyName: "IPF", type: "T"}}])
  .toArray()
  .then(docs => {
    console.log(`got ${docs.length} docs`);
    console.log(docs[0]);
    console.log(docs[1]);
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(`error ${error} in db_methods`));
```

Every document in MyCollection contains a "type" field with varying values; most (but not all) contain a "vocabularyName" field. When I run this in a Meteor method, the returned array size matches the total document count and the first two results documents contain no vocabularyName field at all, and "type: 'S'".  Which does not make any sense.

On a guess, I also tried this pipeline, but it made no difference:

```
[ {"$match": {"$and": [{ "vocabularyName": "IPF"}, {"type": "T"}]}} ]
```

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42460027/2282634

Comment: I don't think so. A "$match: {}" followed by a "$project"  would not do what I want, which is to start by selecting the subset of documents via the $match.

The other aspects of that article are about ways to integrate with Meteor.  I don't think that's my problem, at least not yet.  My concern at this point is to get the $match to work as expected.